# System Sound (Master Volume) is not working anymore

Tags: system, drivers, audio, acer

Since the last system update, my System Sound (Master Volume) is not working anymore.
My sound is working on any Player, if I use HTML5 on YouTube, Flash on Facebook or mp3 in the elementary Music App everything is working, but only with 50% volume and i can adjust the volume between 0 and 50% in the Player, but i cannot adjust the volume in the system (Master Volume). The icon in the System-Tray is inactive, an shows a X.

I already tried to fix it with these commands

> Go-to your terminal and try this.
>
> ```
> sudo alsa force-reload
> ```
>
> And than restart your pc again. Still you face
>   the similar problem than try this.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
>
> sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
> ```
>
> And than
>
> ```
> sudo alsa force-reload
> ```
>
> Now restart and check again. It might be work
>   now.

but is not working for me.

The command "lspci" shows a Intel Audio, but these is wrong.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
05:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
```

My Laptop is a: Acer Aspire 7750G

Sound card is a: Realtek

On Windows 10 i tried to install the original Realtek driver, with the message: Error: device not found.
Only the Acer Realtek Audio Driver works on my Laptop in Windows 7 and 10.

Acer Homepage, [Driver for the Aspire 7750G](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3476?b=1)

Comment: Worked for me with restarting

Comment: Thank you, this works for me off the bat. "sudo alsa force-reload" I'm using Elementary OS Hera (5.1.6) on Dell XPS 15 7590