# Sound simply went kaput

Tags: drivers, sound

I lost sound on my laptop. Speakers and headphones aren't shown on the Sound settings.

The last time everything worked, I had restarted the computer in order to jump over to windows 10. But it was taking a lot of time, so I pressed the power button to force a power off event.

Since I came back to the elementary, no sound.

I've already tried:

sudo alsa force-reload

And also:

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio

Is there anything else I could do or am I facing a reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to anyone interested on this:

I searched a lot and went far away in the hopes of finding a solution to my problem. Nothing worked and I simply got anxious and decided to reinstall the whole thing again (which was VERY time consuming and really frustrating, since I use all sorts of things for PHP and Java development and it's a PIA install all those things one after another, plus the backups, apps and customizations that I had ironed out and completely forgot about how I did it months ago).

That was a tiresome sunday that I wont ever get back, thanks to Linux and its shenanigans.

This is the kind of thing that puts me away from Linux for months.

Anyways, just for referencing, [my problem was pretty much the same thing as this report](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/system-sound-master-volume-is-not-working-anymore). No that it seems to matter, but here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Wowbagger,

This question would be hard to answer by anyone.

May I suggest that in the future you detail the exact Laptop that you have, and in particular the sound card chipset the that particular laptop that you have uses.
Not all laptops are the same, right?  And these particular details are pretty important when trying to troubleshoot something like this.

Comment: Welp, the issue that I linked was described with lots of information regarding the hardware configuration of the system and that didn't help it either. But in the interest of shed some light into this issue:

It's a Dell Inspiron 7560 with a Realtek AC3246. Since Dell sells this machine with Ubuntu installed, I'm pretty sure the hardware is widely supported (before reinstalling eOS, I tested it on WIndows 10 also and it worked flawlessly) . 

In any case, after a lot of searching about no-sound issues on Ubuntu and eOS, I find it doubtful that the hardware is the culprit in this one.